# LocationManager not outputting lat & long positions

Tags: java, android, google-maps, locationmanager

I have succesfully implemented the code so that the google maps works effectively within my application. I am now trying to implement the locationManager and output the latitude and longitude values of my current position but it is crashing.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.androidgooglemap;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager location;
private String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    location = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    location.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(lat));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(lng));
}
```

Could I have some guidance because I am clearly an amateur!

Comment: Just a sidenote: depending on your environment and where you test/develop your application `System.out.println` might not work as you expect it to work.

Comment: I am using the android ADK, Eclipse

Comment: It seems that you havent registered a Listener. Check your tutorial

Comment: could you show me a tutorial, I am working off my knowledge bae to construct this app! Or even an example would be even more benificial

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know exactly what exception you are receiving. But my guess is that you are missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

in your manifest.

Comment: yes I am using that exception and also the `ACCESS_COARSE_Location` permision

Comment: What is the exception (crash) you are receiving? This can be found in the LogCat window.

Comment: invalid provider:null

Comment: To be useful to people trying to answer your question, you should edit your question to include the *full* exception. This way we know exactly what line it happened on and exactly what exception you are receiving.